# Customized Yes/No radio buttons in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

I have to make a custom control made of two radio buttons in ASP MVC. But these radio buttons have to be styled and can have 3 states.
 This is the CSS code for one of the states :

```
.radio_checked{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 14px;
  padding-left: 19px;
  color: #555;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: url(images/radio_checked.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do it, I'm not really good at CSS and Javascript.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I think this is should be help http://blogs.digitss.com/javascript/jquery-javascript/jquery-fancy-custom-radio-and-checkbox/ or http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons it is up to you